# Combine PrimeFaces stacked bar chart model to a line chart model

Tags: charts, primefaces

How to combine stacked bar chart and Line chart in JSF 2.2 using PrimeFaces 8.0?
I followed the show case proposed in PrimeFaces website
But it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure you are using the right examples. There is Charts and ChartsJs. See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-v8

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.